# How can I reject an update in Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-preview

Same as [How can I defer updates in Windows 10 Home?](https://superuser.com/q/923186/370921), but for Windows 10 Pro:

> I prefer knowing what each update does and reading about its impact
>   (including whether it is causing widespread problems for people)
>   before allowing it to be installed on my system.

- or disallowing! Is it possible to "reject" an update altogether, or is it just "deferred" until later? When later: next boot, next day, next month? If rejecting is possible: Is it done as in Win 8.1, or is there a difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/923186/how-can-i-defer-updates-in-windows-10-home?lq=1

Comment: You simple defer the installation it however, eventually, you will be forced to install it  How long you can defer the installation of a required update, has not been announced yet, these updates will be required in the same way `Windows 8.1 Update 1` was required to get future security updates to Windows 8.1.

Comment: Only Windows 10 Pro and Enterprise [have the ability to turn off Windows updates](https://4sysops.com/archives/disable-windows-update-in-windows-10/), giving you time to study the ramifications, but it appears you cannot pick and choose updates to install anymore, so sad.

Comment: @Moab - You can't choose not to install `Windows 8.1 Update 1`, if you want security updates that is, honestly it is about time.  Apple does not give you a choice, if you want support, you install up to a support version.  I see little difference in the Windows 10 model.

Comment: I still think it sucks. Don't care what apple does.

Comment: @Moab: Could you please convert your first comment into an answer? Your link provided the information I was looking for! (If I had enough reputation to do so, I would also upvote your comment.)

Answer (score -1):

The steps are similar to 'reject' or 'hide' an update. Go to Windows Updates->Important Updates. Right click the update and click "Hide Update". That's it!

Comment: According to the page linked in Moab's comment, updates will not be shown in Windows Updates but directly installed, therefore **there is nothing to click on**. The page also explains how to change that.

Comment: @ParasSidhu - This use to be the case.  This is no longer entirely true with specific versions of Windows 10.

Comment: Ok, it seems I am using an older build. The final answer will come on 29th July.